# In X86 Platform, does the DMA operation mean to move data between MMIO addr space and system memory addr space?

Tags: linux-kernel, dma

On the modern X86/X86_64 platform, due to MMIO mechanism, are DMA operations to move data between MMIO address space and memory address space? In the Linux kernel, I see that there is a `dma_addr_t` definition.  Is this type used for MMIO addresses?

Answer (score 0):

In general, a DMA operation just refers to a device other than the CPU accessing memory.  On x86, there are not separate MMIO and RAM address spaces -- everything is unified.  Some examples of typical DMA operations:

- A network card might receive a packet from the network and use DMA to write the packet contents into the system's RAM.
- A SATA controller might get a write command and use DMA to read the data to send to the hard disk from system RAM.
- A graphics card might use DMA to read texture data from system RAM into its own video memory.  The video memory is visible to the system CPU through a PCI BAR (MMIO), but that's not really relevant here.

The `dma_addr_t` type holds a "bus address" in Linux.  The address that, for example, a PCI device (like a NIC / SATA controller / GPU) sees a given part of memory mapped at can be different than the address the CPU uses.  So Linux has the abstraction of "DMA mapping" to handle this difference.

In the first example above, the network stack would allocate a buffer in RAM, and then pass it to a `dma_map` function to get a bus address that it hands to the NIC.  The NIC would use that address to write the packet into memory.

In older x86 systems, there wasn't really any difference between the physical address that the CPU used and the bus address that external devices used, and the `dma_map` functions were pretty much NOPs.  However, with modern technologies like VT-d, the bus address that  a PCI device uses might be completely different than the CPU's physical address, and so it is important to do the DMA mapping and use a `dma_addr_t` for all addresses that are used by external DMA devices.

Comment: Hi Roland, thanks your answer. So the dma_addr_t is the bus address, may it be a MMIO address? What I mean is that if the network card has a buffer memory to receive data as you mentioned and the buffer memory maps it to system address space per MMIO mechanism, in this case, the dma address is the MMIO address, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, bus addresses / `dma_addr_t` can be in MMIO space.  The network card example is pretty unusual, since pretty much all network cards do DMA into system RAM for incoming packets.  But you might DMA into GPU texture memory from another PCI card for GPGPU or something.

Comment: Thanks, I got the it. In the IOV area, specially in Intel VT-d, the MMIO space could be the DMA address.